# asp.net session security

Tags: asp.net

If I put some pretty sensitive information in a session variable, how secure is it? Can it be access by a client writing a rogue page and making an ajax call to my application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to store that data between requests, then, you should store in the server side.

To store information to use between requests you have these options:

- Hidden Fields: You should never use this to store sensitive information, because the user (or an malicious user) can get that information;
- ViewState: You should avoid to store sensitive information here, but if you really, really really need it, you should encrypt the viewstate;
- Cookies: You should never use this to store sensitive information. Like the Hidden Field, it's easy to see the information inside.
- Session: If you really need to store that data, here is the place you should use. In IT world, there is nothing safe, but this is the safer place to save that information.

I think I didn't forget anything.

Comment: Do you think session is a safe place to store a credit card number or a userID for example?

Comment: Well, if you need to save it between request (and you should not Imho) you should use SecureString to do that. Credit card number is a very sensitive information, so probably you should arch your application in a different way.

Comment: When storing credit card information (even between pages) there are pretty strict regulations on that.  This data should never exist on the client side.  When stored on a server, even temporarily, you need to ensure that no other users can access this data.  Savest bet, don't store this.  If you must store it beyond an individual transaction then see this link for PCI standards (compliance): http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pcifaqs.php   You do not want to open yourself to risk (e.g. getting sued / fined for lack of compliance)

Comment: Also, Session data is not "secure".  True, it exists on the server side, but if anyone gained access to the server they would have access to the public session data.  If you were to store credit card info in session you had better encrypt it with an asymetric key at a minimum.  Also, be sure that the server the session data is stored on is locked down (SSL, and only allow machines in your architecture to communicate.  Avoid machines that have full internet access.)

Answer (score 3):

In short, because it's stored on the server, it should be safe.

The variable will be safe unless you expose it. You can't just arbitrarily make ajax calls (or any other type of calls) to retrieve session variables. You'd have to be able to write code that executes on the server.

However, if someone is able to hijack your user's session they'd be able to see it on any page you display it (if you do). This security concern isn't restricted to session variables though. If you're worried about this, [you might want to use HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509862/avoid-session-hijacking-for-web-applications).

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with Credit card data you have to be very careful.  This is not something you can take lightly as there are all sorts of compliance regulations and laws to consider.  Basically, Session is the only place I would consider ... if I did.  I would still encrypt it.  In truth, however, I would recommend not storing any credit card data if you can help it.  There are lots of payment systems out there, and banks provide processing tools as well.  If you let the user put it in durring the transaction, keep the entry secure, and store none of it, that is the safest from a legal perspective.  You are not bearing risk by keeping the data.

If you MUST keep credit card data see the following PCI regulations:
[PCI Compliance Guide](http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pcifaqs.php#2)

Additionally, you may find this guide on secure session usage helpful:
[ASP.NET Fast, Scalable, Secure Sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163730.aspx)

Comment: Just read your comments and answer and I totally agree with you. I up vote the answer to give it more visibility. Just a note: credit card information has a special treatment, if you're processing a request with credit card information, you MUST be PCI compliance, even if you don't store it. If that's the case, don't try to understand PCI compliance by yourself and contact a consultant with experience on that.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Thank you.  I have been looking more deeply into Tokenization over the past couple years.  That is what I would consider the ideal method if one had to store any of the data - keep it separated from all other human access and only give system access through encrypted channels.  I love this approach as it allows you to drastically reduce your PCI footprint by removing all sensitive data from the database and eliminating the risk of internal compromise (remove the incentive for attack).